# How do I delete lines from a file that have certain variables with delimiters?

Tags: php

I want to clear an entire line from a file after finding specific variables that match with that line. My code works to clear the file and put the lines back but it is not skipping the intended line. I believe it is an issue with the key I have created. How should the key be formatted if it is incorrect?

Each line in the file is separated by a colon. I store each line as "$name:$date:$contact:$compType:$os:$service\n:

My code so far is:

```
            //load file into $fc array
            $key = ($name AND $date AND $contact);

            $fc=file("repairOrder.txt");

            //open same file and use "w" to clear file

            $f=fopen("repairOrder.txt","w");

            //loop through array using foreach
            
            foreach($fc as $line)
            {
                  if (!strstr($line,$key)) //look for $key in each line
                        fputs($f,$line); //place $line back in file
            }
            fclose($f);
        }
```

Comment: `$key = ($name AND $date AND $contact)` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Is there another way of phrasing to search for those specific variables?

Comment: It sets it to either `true` or `false` depending on the result of the AND conditions.

Comment: You want to remove lines that match all 3 variables?

Comment: `if (!(strstr($line, $name) && strstr($line, $date) && strstr($line, $contact)))`

Comment: Skip the line that matches those 3 variables. Gotcha, I pretty much was using the ANDs as a placeholder.

Comment: Barmar you are a genius. I did not think of putting it into the if statement like that.

Comment: But `strstr()` doesn't distribute over logical operators, and when you assign the variable it doesn't preserve them.

Comment: you seem to be confused about the basics of how variables work. They're not macros, they don't remember the expression that was used to assign them. So when you use the variable, you just get its value, it doesn't substitute the original expression in its place.